# Python how to convert this type of list to dictionary

Tags: python

```
[["4040", ["4040", "1.04862754", 4]], ["4040.1", ["4040.1", "0.25906621", 1]], ["4040.2", ["4040.2", "0.954", 1]]]
```

**what i want is:**

```
{"4040": ["4040", "1.04862754", 4]}, {"4040.1": ["4040.1", "0.25906621", 1]}, {"4040.2": ["4040.2", "0.954", 1]}
```

i want to send this data to redis in json format but had a difficulty on converting. Actually i already write this data in dictionary but before sending to redis i need to sort keys so python converts it to a list

Comment: yes it throws: `Invalid input of type: 'list'. Convert to a byte, string or number first.
`

Comment: There is an ambiguity here. `{"4040": ["4040", "1.04862754", 4]}, {"4040.1": ["4040.1", "0.25906621", 1]}, {"4040.2": ["4040.2", "0.954", 1]}` is not a dictionary. It is a tuple of dictionaries. Please clarify: do you want a tuple of dictionaries, or do you want one dictionary? If it's the latter, what does it look like?

Comment: "i want to send this data to redis in json format (...) but before sending to redis i need to sort keys" => you're aware that json objects are __unordered__ collections of key:values, are you ? (and FWIW, python dicts are unordered too, at least until 3.7.x)

Comment: BTW, what have you tried that did't work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using slicing:

```
print({x[0]: x[1:] for x in lst})
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{'4040': [['4040', '1.04862754', 4]], '4040.1': [['4040.1', '0.25906621', 1]], '4040.2': [['4040.2', '0.954', 1]]}
```

**OR**

```
print(dict(lst))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{'4040': ['4040', '1.04862754', 4], '4040.1': ['4040.1', '0.25906621', 1], '4040.2': ['4040.2', '0.954', 1]}
```

**OR**

If you want a list of dicts separated:

```
print([{x[0]: x[1]} for x in lst])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[
   {'4040': ['4040', '1.04862754', 4]}, {'4040.1': ['4040.1', '0.25906621', 1]}, {'4040.2': ['4040.2', '0.954', 1]}
]
```

**OR**

*(Often things are simple but we complicate them ourselves)*

```
print([{k:v} for k, v in lst])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[
  {'4040': ['4040', '1.04862754', 4]}, {'4040.1': ['4040.1', '0.25906621', 1]}, {'4040.2': ['4040.2', '0.954', 1]}
]
```

Comment: Here, each value is wrapped in an extra list though. Not sure that behavior was desired?

Comment: @TomMP Added an alternative ;)

Comment: Nice, but it's still not quite what OP asked for as far as I can tell. They wanted each entry in your dictionary to be a dictionary, not have it all in one. It was difficult to tell from their formatting, I made the same mistake in the first version of my answer. Nonetheless, this is pretty nice I had no idea python would just "figure out" how to cast a list like that to a dict.

Comment: @TomMP added another alternative! ;)

Comment: @DirtyBit not need for slicing here, you can just unpack.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers `[{k:v} for k, v in lst]` is what you meant perhaps?

Comment: @DirtyBit exactly

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Just saw you want three dictionaries, altered the code accordingly.

```py
my_list = [["4040", ["4040", "1.04862754", 4]], ["4040.1", ["4040.1", "0.25906621", 1]], ["4040.2", ["4040.2", "0.954", 1]]]

result = []

for elem in my_list:
    my_dict = {elem[0]: elem[1]}
    result.append(my_dict)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[
  {'4040': ['4040', '1.04862754', 4]},
  {'4040.1': ['4040.1', '0.25906621', 1]},
  {'4040.2': ['4040.2', '0.954', 1]}
]
```

Or, as pointed out in the comments, use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and save yourself a fair amount of lines:

```py
result = [{k:v} for k, v in my_list]
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: or more simply: `result = [{k:v} for k, v in my_list]`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert that list to a list of dictionaries, a list comprehension will suffice:

```py
>>> list_of_kv = [["4040", ["a", "b", 4]], ["4040.1", ["d", "e", 1]]]

>>> [{k: v} for k, v in list_of_kv]
[{'4040': ['a', 'b', 4]}, {'4040.1': ['d', 'e', 1]}]
```

If you instead want a single dictionary, the builtin `dict` class can handle it:

```py
>>> dict(list_of_kv)
{'4040': ['a', 'b', 4], '4040.1': ['d', 'e', 1]}
```

Comment: congratulations, this is the first answer doing the simple obvious thing !

Comment: Here is a complementary up-vote from my side as well +1

Comment: "It's been an honor, sir."

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> L = [["4040", ["4040", "1.04862754", 4]], ["4040.1", ["4040.1", "0.25906621", 1]], ["4040.2", ["4040.2", "0.954", 1]]]
>>> dict(map(tuple, L))
{'4040': ['4040', '1.04862754', 4], '4040.1': ['4040.1', '0.25906621', 1], '4040.2': ['4040.2', '0.954', 1]}
```

`map(tuple, L)` transforms `L[0]`, `L[1]`, ... into tuples. `dict` converts `k, v` tuples to dictionary entries.